# I am struggling to understand why I am getting an error message for a method in my RPN calculator

Tags: ruby, calculator, rpn

Everything seems to be functioning in my code except for the .evaluate method.

I am getting the error message:

```
Failures:

  1) RPNCalculator evaluates a string
     Failure/Error: expect(calculator.evaluate("1 2 3 * +")).to eq(
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `times' for [1, 2, 3]:Array
     # ./lib/12_rpn_calculator.rb:78:in `block in evaluate'
     # ./lib/12_rpn_calculator.rb:75:in `each'
     # ./lib/12_rpn_calculator.rb:75:in `evaluate'
     # ./spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb:144:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00381 seconds (files took 0.10201 seconds to load)
9 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/12_rpn_calculator_spec.rb:143 # RPNCalculator evaluates a string
```

from the program:

```
    class RPNCalculator





 def initialize
    @calculator = Array.new
  end

  def push(x)
      @calculator << x 
  end 

  def value 
      @calculator.last
  end 


  def plus
      error_message

          sum = @calculator.pop + @calculator.pop 
      @calculator << sum
  end 



  def minus 
      error_message
      #@calculator.reverse!
      #difference = @calculator.pop - @calculator.pop
      first = @calculator.pop
      second = @calculator.pop 
      difference = second - first 
      #
      @calculator << difference
  end 

  def divide 
      error_message
      @calculator = @calculator.map {|n| n.to_f}
      divisor = @calculator.pop ; dividend = @calculator.pop
      quotient = (dividend / divisor) 
      @calculator << quotient 

  end 

  def times
      error_message
      puts @calculator.inspect

      @calculator.map! {|n| n.to_f}
      product = @calculator.pop * @calculator.pop 
      @calculator << product 
  end

  def error_message 
       raise "calculator is empty" if @calculator.size < 2 
   end 

  def tokens(string)
      operators = ["+", "-", "/", "*"]
      string.split.map! {|i| 
      if operators.include?(i)
          i.to_sym
      else 
          i.to_i
      end 
      }
  end 

  def evaluate(rpn)
      @calculator = tokens(rpn).select {|t| t.is_a?Integer}
      operators = tokens(rpn).select{|t| t.is_a?Symbol}

      operators.each {|n| 
      @calculator.plus if n == :+ 
      @calculator.minus if n == :- 
      @calculator.times if n == :* 
      @calculator.divide if n == :/ }

  end 

end
```

It seems to me that the .times method should work for Arrays. So, I want to understand what is going on. Is there some fundamental problem? or is there a typo? Generally, why am I getting the error message?

edit: here are the specs I need to pass:

```
require "12_rpn_calculator"

describe RPNCalculator do
  attr_accessor :calculator

  before do
    @calculator = RPNCalculator.new
  end

  it "adds two numbers" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.plus
    expect(calculator.value).to eq(5)
  end

  it "adds three numbers" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.push(4)
    calculator.plus
    expect(calculator.value).to eq(7)
    calculator.plus
    expect(calculator.value).to eq(9)
  end

  it "subtracts the second number from the first number" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.minus
    expect(calculator.value).to eq(-1)
  end

  it "adds and subtracts" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.push(4)
    calculator.minus
    expect(calculator.value).to eq(-1)
    calculator.plus
    expect(calculator.value).to eq(1)
  end

  it "multiplies and divides" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.push(4)
    calculator.divide
    expect(calculator.value).to eq((3.0 / 4.0))
    calculator.times
    expect(calculator.value).to eq(2.0 * (3.0 / 4.0))
  end

  it "resolves operator precedence unambiguously" do
    # 1 2 + 3 * => (1 + 2) * 3
    calculator.push(1)
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.plus
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.times
    expect(calculator.value).to eq((1+2)*3)

    @calculator = RPNCalculator.new
    # 1 2 3 * + => 1 + (2 * 3)
    calculator.push(1)
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.times
    calculator.plus
    expect(calculator.value).to eq(1+(2*3))
  end

  it "fails informatively when there's not enough values stacked away" do
    expect {
      calculator.plus
    }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")

    expect {
      calculator.minus
    }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")

    expect {
      calculator.times
    }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")

    expect {
      calculator.divide
    }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")
  end

  # extra credit
  it "tokenizes a string" do
    expect(calculator.tokens("1 2 3 * + 4 5 - /")).to eq(
      [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
    )
  end

  # extra credit
  it "evaluates a string" do
    expect(calculator.evaluate("1 2 3 * +")).to eq(
      ((2 * 3) + 1)
    )

    expect(calculator.evaluate("4 5 -")).to eq(
      (4 - 5)
    )

    expect(calculator.evaluate("2 3 /")).to eq(
      (2.0 / 3.0)
    )

    expect(calculator.evaluate("1 2 3 * + 4 5 - /")).to eq(
      (1.0 + (2 * 3)) / (4 - 5)
    )
  end
end
```

as you can see, ".times" is a method defined in the class that I intended to work on arrays. I imagined that I would "evaluate" a string by converting it into an Array and then running the custom methods on it, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `@calculator` is an Array, so in order to call `.times` on it, Array would need to know how to respond to `.times`. I think you want to call `.times` on an instance of RPNCalculator, not on an Array. Since you are calling `.times` from an instance method, you would call `self.times` or, to follow Ruby convention, simply omit `self` and call `times if n == :*`. The whole thing might be a bit less confusing if your array of operands were called something like `operands` instead of `calculator.`

Comment: *It seems to me that the .times method should work for Arrays.* -- You can look through the ruby docs for the class Array here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html.  Where do you see a times() method?  *Generally, why am I getting the error message?*  Because you can't write: `[1, 2, 3].times()` nor `@calculator = [1, 2, 3]; @calculator.times()` because the Array class does not define a `times()` method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". It helps us help you when you reduce your code to the bare minimum necessary to duplicate the problem. And, during that process you'll often find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it something like this:

```
class RPNCalculator

  def initialize(s)
    @operators = []
    @operands = []
    s.split.map { |i| 
      case i
      when '+', '-', '/', '*'
        @operators << i.to_sym
      else
        @operands << (i['.'] ? i.to_f : i.to_i)
      end
    }
  end

  def count_operands 
    raise "calculator is empty" if @operands.size < 2 
  end 

  def output
    puts @operands.join(',')
  end

  def process(operator)
    @operands.unshift([@operands.shift, @operands.shift].inject(operator))
  end

  def evaluate
    @operators.each do |o| 
      count_operands()
      process(o)
    end
  end 
end

rpn = RPNCalculator.new('355.0 113 /')
rpn.evaluate
rpn.output
```

Which, when run, outputs:

```
3.1415929203539825
```

You're not using your class definition of RPNCalculator correctly. In your code `@calculator` is an array, but Arrays don't know anything about your various methods because they're part of RPNCalculator, not Array. Just because a variable is in a class doesn't mean it's inherited the methods of that class; It's still whatever type it was to begin with.

Note: You *can* add the methods to that class in various ways in Ruby, but there are dragons down that road so you'll want to understand what you're doing before you try because you can break things unintentionally.

```
[@operands.shift, @operands.shift].inject(operator)
```

is the magical part, taking advantage of `inject`:

```
[1] (pry) main: 0> [1, 1].inject(:+)
2
[2] (pry) main: 0> [355.0, 113].inject(:/)
3.1415929203539825
```

Comment: Thanks, that is clearly much cleaner. Though I have to work with the rspec tests assigned to me.